# C#でHTMLテキストをインデントする方法はありませんか？

Tags: .net, c#, html5, html-agility-pack

VS2013 .NetFramework4.0環境で、 HtmlAgilityPackを使用して煩雑なHTMLをパーズし、整形したHTMLに変換するプログラムを作成しています。

しかし、HtmlAgilityPackにはHTMLテキストをインデントする機能はないようでした。
XMLを自動インデントする方法はあるのですが、変換処理が必要になってしまう・preタグの中にインデント文字が入ってしまうなど少し面倒です。
C#でHTMLテキストをインデントする簡単な方法はありますでしょうか。HTML5のタグに対応しているものだとなお良いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## HtmlTidyPackについて

[別の回答に含まれる英語版SOの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610903/718426)に書かれていたHtmlTidyPackのURLを開くと、

> This site is no longer being maintained. If you've arrived here via wherever and you're looking for some software, maybe these links will help:
> （このサイトはメンテナンスされていません。ソフトウェアなどをお探しでしたら、以下のリンクが参考になると思います（意訳））

とあり、当該githubのURLは[TidyManaged](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged)ですが5年以上メンテナンスされていないようです。
（そもそも本家のtidyが2008年から更新されていないですので仕方ないですね）

## NuGet Package

そこで、[HtmlTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)のラッパである[HTML Tidy Library Project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libtidy/)または[TidyNetPortable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TidyNetPortable/)を以下のように、NuGet経由でインストールするのがいいかなとおもいテストしてみました。

```
Install-Package TidyNetPortable
```

結果、VS2013環境では両方使えませんでした...
TidyNetPortableはそもそも実装が足りないのか、実装しても動かず、ドキュメントもありません。また、HTML Tidy Library Projectは.Net Framework 4.0環境にはNuGetでインストールできませんでした。

## tidy wrapperを探してビルド

NuGetで提供されているパッケージがつかえないので、比較的新しめのプロジェクトを探してdllをビルドして使うしかないようです。さがしてみると[EfTidyNet: .NET Wrapper for Tidy library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24105/EfTidyNet-NET-Wrapper-for-Tidy-library)というのを発見しました。

- Download EfTidy 1.0.2.0.source

とあるのをダウンロードし、Buildしてdllを生成します。このときx64環境であれば、構成がデフォルトでWin32になっていますので、環境に合わせて修正してbuildしてください。

dllを生成したら、ソリューションエクスプローラーのReferences（参照）上で右クリックして、Add References(参照の追加)をしてください。

[image: 参照の追加]

次のようなダイアログが表示されますので、Browse（日本語版だと参照？）をクリックして、前の手順でビルドしたdllを選択します。
[image: 参照の追加ダイアログ]

そして、次のようなプログラムを書きます。
（ここでは、html5にtidy処理しています）

```
...
using EfTidyNet;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...
String text = File.ReadAllText("test.html");             

TidyNet objTidyNet = new TidyNet();
objTidyNet.Option.OutputType(EfTidyNet.EfTidyOpt.EOutputType.HtmlOut);
objTidyNet.Option.NewBlockLevelTags("article aside audio details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup menutidy nav section source summary track video");
objTidyNet.Option.NewInlineTags("command embed keygen source track wbr");
objTidyNet.Option.NewEmptyTags("canvas command data datalist embed keygen mark meter output progress time wbr");
objTidyNet.Option.Indent(EfTidyNet.EfTidyOpt.EIndentScheme.AUTOINDENT);
objTidyNet.Option.IndentSpace(2);
objTidyNet.Option.WrapLen(0);
objTidyNet.Option.DropEmptyParas(true);
objTidyNet.Option.TidyMark(false);
objTidyNet.Option.Clean(true);

String result = null;
objTidyNet.TidyMemToMem(text, ref result);
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"(\r\n){2}", "\r\n"); //tidyのオプションでどうしても消せず...
this.textBox1.Text = result;
```

test.htmlは次のような内容です。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>xxxxxxxxxx</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header,
        hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article><h1>xxxxxxxxxx</h1><p>xxxx</p><aside><h3>xxx</h3><ul class="referenceLinks"><li><a href="http://xx.html" target="_blank">http://xxx.html</a></li><li><a href="http://xxxxx.html" target="_blank">http://xx.html</a></li></ul></aside><section><h2>yyyyyy</h2><p>Pyyyyy</p></section><section><h2>zzzzzzz</h2><p>Pzzzzzzz<strong>ssss</strong><strong>aaaaa</strong><strong>ssss</strong>zzzzzz</p><figure><figcaption>zzzzzz</figcaption><img src="aaa.png" alt="aaaaa"></figure><p>bbbbb</p></section></article>
</body>
</html>
```

上記プログラムに食わせると、以下のような出力を得られます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <title>xxxxxxxxxx</title><!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
      article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header,
        hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>xxxxxxxxxx</h1>
    <p>xxxx</p>
    <aside>
      <h3>xxx</h3>
      <ul class="referenceLinks">
        <li><a href="http://xx.html" target="_blank">http://xxx.html</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://xxxxx.html" target="_blank">http://xx.html</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <h2>yyyyyy</h2>
      <p>Pyyyyy</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>zzzzzzz</h2>
      <p>Pzzzzzzz<strong>ssss</strong><strong>aaaaa</strong><strong>ssss</strong>zzzzzz</p>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>zzzzzz</figcaption><img src="aaa.png" alt="aaaaa">
      </figure>
      <p>bbbbb</p>
    </section>
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```

というわけで無事beautifyされました。
tidyのオプションの詳細については、[HTML Tidy Configuration Options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html)を確認して下さい。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
ビルドからやらないといけないみたいですね。
もっと簡単にできないものですかねー

Answer (score 2):

Html Agility Packでは出来ないらしいので、HtmlTidyPackを使うらしいです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593147/html-agility-pack-make-code-look-neat

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Mark.Tidy;

namespace CleanupHtml{
/// <summary>
/// http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931
/// </summary>
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html =
                new WebClient().DownloadString(
                    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593147/html-agility-pack-make-code-look-neat/2610903#2610903");

            using (Document doc = new Document(html))
            {
                doc.ShowWarnings = false;
                doc.Quiet = true;
                doc.OutputXhtml = true;
                doc.OutputXml = true;
                doc.IndentBlockElements = AutoBool.Yes;
                doc.IndentAttributes = false;
                doc.IndentCdata = true;
                doc.AddVerticalSpace = false;
                doc.WrapAt = 120;

                doc.CleanAndRepair();

                string output = doc.Save();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                File.WriteAllText("output.htm", output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
後に回答された方も仰っているように、詳解されたTidyのライブラリを試してみたのですが、自分の環境では読む込むことができませんでした。
もしかしたら、自分の環境でビルドしたものを使えば動いたのかもしれません。